# How to properly compose functional components that have infinite scrolling logic

Tags: reactjs, use-state, react-functional-component

I'm converting a class component to functional component for practice. It has a ref object to contain some variables for the component, such as IntersectionObserver object to implement infinite scrolling.

The issue starts from here. The callback function of the IntersectionObserver calls a function(says update) defined in the component to load more data. Because the IntersectionObserver is defined inside the useRef, the update function is **the function bound when the component gets initialized**. So the value of the state that is used in the update function is also the value of the initial state.

How can I compose this functional component in a proper way?

Backbone demo

```
export default function A(props) {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    pageNo: 1,
    isLoading: false,
    items: []
  });

  const update = useCallback(() => {
    setState(state => ({...state, isLoading: true}));

    someApi(state.pageNo);
    setState(state => ({
      ...state,
      pageNo: pageNo + 1
    }));

    setState(state => ({...state, isLoading: false}));
  }, [isLoading, pageNo]);

  const observerCallback = useCallback((entries, observer) => {
    for (const entry of entries) {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        observer.disconnect();
        update();
      }
    }
  }, [update]);
  const observer = useRef(new IntersectionObserver(observerCallback)); // The callback is the function binding the update function that binds some of the initial state
  const lastEl = useRef(null);
  const preLastEl = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    update();
  }, [props]);

  if (lastEl.current && lastEl.current != preLastEl.current) {
    preLastEl.current = lastEl.current;
    observer.observe(lastEl.current);
  }

  return (
    <SomeProgressBar style={{ display: state.isLoading ? "" : "none" }}/>
    {
      state.items.map((item) => <B ... ref={lastEl}/>)
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: You don't use `props` object as a dep array, and it even not defined. Also your `update` function will always render `isLoading = false` as someAPI is async....

Comment: @DennisVash thank you for letting me know that :) My actual code is using typescript and I tried to write the backbone demo as simple as possible for readers and I forgot putting props in parameter, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly why you're using the `ref` and why you can't do it differently. so in case you have to do it this way, your `refs` are dependent to `state` object and they need to be changed when the state are changed so you should use a `useEffect` to change the `refs` based on new `state`. try to implement one of these two steps:

`1`

```
  const refs = useRef({
    lastEl: undefined,
    observer: new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
      ...
      update(state.pageNo); // This is the update function bound when the instance of this component gets initialized
    });
  }); 
  
  useEffect(() => {
    update(state.pageNo);
  }, [props]);
 
  function update(pageNo = 1) {
    setState(prev => ({...prev, isLoading: true}));

    someApi(pageNo); // state.pageNo will be always 1

    setState(prev => ({...prev, isLoading: false}));
  }
```

`2` in case above code didn't work try this

```
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if(state.pageNo){
        refs.current = {
            lastEl: undefined,
            observer: new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
            ...
            update(state.pageNo); // This is the update function bound when the instance of this component gets initialized
          });
        }
    }
  }, [state.pageNo])
```